# What is the minimum possible probability of a bloom filter?

Tags: redis, bloom-filter

I have a use case where I need to check as efficiently as possible if a hash **certainly doesn't exist** in 15 billion records (and counting). Those checks are performed at rates of thousands per second. 
I really like the [Redis bloom filter](https://redislabs.com/blog/rebloom-bloom-filter-datatype-redis/) implementation and I'm currently test feeding my bloom filters. I'm creating 15 filters holding 1b records each:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> bf.reserve articles15 0.1 1000000000
```

As far as I understand bloom filters, if the result from `bf.exists` is `0`, then it is certain that the element is not present in the filter. This is all I care about. I don't care about false negatives as I will never check for `1`

In the command above 0.1 is the error rate as Redis calls it, a.k.a. probability.

**The actual question:** What is the highest number that I can safely set to have the minimum possible bloom filter size? Redis allows me to set even `1`, but I suppose this won't work. Can I set `0.9`?

Answer (score 2):

You can, in theory, but this makes no sense. If you don't care about false negatives, just assume everything is 0 and have a 100% false negative rate :)

So you do care about false negatives to a degree or you wouldn't use a bloom filter, right? Now ask yourself what is your real need.

Comment: OK it was late and I didn't think this through :) I don't care about false positives, not negatives. Thanks for the correction. My need is this: I fetch a list of items every x seconds. I store a hash of each item in a database, so when I fetch all items again, I can find which ones are NOT in my database. My current database is ~15 billion hashes spread across several MySQL instances. There are several thousand hash checks per second. Needles to say this is inefficient. I wanted to utilize bloom filters, but only to check if something is surely not already in my hash database. Is this doable?

Comment: OK I'm stupid... It looks like what I'm after here isn't feasible with bloom filters... I can use them as a quick initial lookup, but I still need to the keep my old data in case the filter returns `true`, because it might actually be `false` and then I will ignore this item as if it is already in my database. Oh well... back to the drawing board.

Comment: Sounds like what you need is a simple LRU cache.